# wordpress add settings to user page

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, settings

I would like to add a field to the user profile edit page in wordpress. The field should consist of one checkbox and should only be edited by the 'admin'.

Does anyone have an idea where I can find this or how I can do this?

I have searched through the entire Wordpress codex however i couldn't find anything helpful..

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can check Cimy user extra fields http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/

Answer (score 0):

I was just reading [this article](http://www.dquinn.net/adding-custom-user-meta-profile-fields-wordpress/) on how to do what you have mentioned above i.e. adding a field for a user profile. The article goes through each step as to what is required and how that process can be done. If you are familiar with php/html you should be able to make this change fairly quickly.

Comment: The problem with link answers is that they don't live forever. When answering you should include a summary of the page in your answer so it remains valid without the link.